# Can't use the middle mouse button

Tags: modeling, camera, selection-tools

This is my first time using Blender and the shortcut button <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> doesn't seem to be working for moving the object along the axes. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You will only see the Axis you can snap to once you start dragging! So, press <kbd>G</kbd>, hold <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and then drag, and select the axis you want to move across!